Weird camera tracking despite solve error close to 0
I'm trying to understand why my tracked camera is behaving randomly despite the very low solve error. Any clue?

File attached here


The solve error is not actually low if it doesn't work, is it?.. The file you attached does not include the footage.

If I'm not mistaking, the solver can totally find a solution with a 0.01px error while it doesn't match at all your camera. The more trackers there are, the less likely you'll get this issue I think (probability to get that tends to 0). My guess is that by adding a single tracker, you'll already won't get this low error.
